# How to avoid use of .Select and .Activate in creating a table?

Tags: vba, excel

I’ve been told that the use of .Select and .Workbooks.Activate is not really a good way to write Vba.  The code below tends to work perfectly and there doesn’t seem to be any real issues.  The Activeworkbook is not a problem because of Workbooks("FUA.XLSM").Activate.  My question is then, what would a good alternative/approach?
I’m sorry if this is a waste of time or it’s a stupid question, but I have heard that using these methods are not a good way to do it in the long run.  I am worried that this will not work or create problems in the future.  It should be noted that without Workbooks("FUA.XLSM").Activate the code tends to create errors as it gets confused about which workbook it should select.
In short, my question is, how am I able to avoid using Select and .Activate as to mitigate potential for errors in the future?
Code is as follows..

```
  Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ha.csv")
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("FUA")
   Dim sht1 As Worksheet
   Dim sht2 As Worksheet
  Dim copyRange As Range
  Set sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set sht2 = wb2.Sheets("Ha")
With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Range("AA3").Select
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("AA3"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).row
    Else
        lastRow = 1
    End If
End With
Workbooks("FUA.XLSM").Activate
   Range("AA3").Select
    sht1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    sht1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
        ">=-1000000000000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=1000000000000000"
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ha.csv")
          Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb2.Sheets("Ha").Paste
 wb2.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Ha.csv", FileFormat:= _
        xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        Workbooks("Ha.csv").Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Most of the `.Select`/`.Activate` can be removed, if I'm reading this right. You have your ranges, mostly, specified. You do have one `Selection.SpecialCells(xlcellTypeVisible).Copy` that should just be `Range("Table1[#All]").SpecialCells....`  Try removing/commenting out the Select/Activate lines and see if it works as expected or not.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks Batman.. uh Bruce.  If I remove Range("AA3").Select below Workbooks("FUA.XLSM").Activate and also Range("Table1[#All]").Select it tends not to work as it creates a table at the selected cell.  It gets confused if I don't specify this and it also gets confused at which workbook to select if no Workbook.Activate so I'm kind of puzzled how to avoid this.  The other Select can be removed though.

Comment: `Workbooks("wbk.xlsx").Activate // Range("A1").Select // Selection.Value = 1` can be rewritten as `Workbooks("wbk.xlsx").Range("A1").Value = 1`.

Comment: (a) Your code does a `Range("AA3").Select` immediately after your `Workbooks("FUA.XLSM").Activate`.  Which sheet in FUA.XLSM would be active at that time (because `Range("AA3")` will be referring to cell AA3 on the active sheet)?  (b) Earlier (just after a `With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")` statement), you do a `Range("AA3").Select` to select cell AA3 of the active (and only?) sheet within Ha.csv.  What is the purpose of that `Select`?

Comment: @YowE3K Good point.  Thanks for that.  There is no use for them being there they are moot. Range("Table1[#All]").Select and Workbooks("FUA.XLSM").Activate still needs to be replaced

Comment: @BruceWayne You were right, Bruce.  Most of the selects can be removed.  Not sure why I didn't think so. I'm not really sure how I can replace the Workbooks("FUA.XLSM").Activate and Range("Table1[#All]").Select.

Comment: `Range("Table1[#All]").Select` shouldn't be needed if you use `Range("Table1[#All]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` instead of `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`.  (I don't use Excel tables, but I can't see why that wouldn't work.)  And if you don't use the unqualified `Range`, you shouldn't need the `Activate`.  As far as I can see, everything else seems to be qualified.

Comment: You should also be able to get rid of the second `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ha.csv")`.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for your suggestions.  I've tested removing 
  Range("AA3").Select and .Activate further and it tends to creates error 1004 but not before creating a table in the wherever cell is highlighted as its not searching correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably get down voted for saying this but If it ain't broke don't fix it.  Your code works fine already, no real reason to change unless it doesn't work or errors popping up.  Sounds like you've tested it already.

Your code is already optimised and faster though here is an alternative for the sake of avoiding Select.  If you get error 1004 with select methods similar to like the last line `sht2.Range("A:I").Copy Columns(last_col + 1).PasteSpecial` in the code below it will continue anyway.

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("XXX.XLSM")                ' from here, use wb1 to refer to fua.xlsm

    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook                      ' ditto for wb2
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ha.csv")

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet                          ' ditto for sht1
    Set sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
     Set sht2 = wb2.Sheets("Ha")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sht1.Cells) <> 0 Then

        LastRow = sht1.Cells.Find( _
                        What:="*", _
                        After:=sht1.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If




  sht1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, sht1.Range("A:I"), xlYes).Name = "Table1"





    sht1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
                Field:=9, _
                Criteria1:=">=-1000000000000", _
                Operator:=xlAnd, _
                Criteria2:="<=1000000000000000"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False          ' not sure if needed



      sht1.Range("A:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    On Error Resume Next
   sht2.Range("A:I").Copy Columns(last_col + 1).PasteSpecial
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True           ' not sure if needed

    wb2.Save                                   ' already C:\Users\Ha.csv
    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code rewritten.
I think it has the same functionality.

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("FUA.XLSM")                ' from here, use wb1 to refer to fua.xlsm

    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook                      ' ditto for wb2
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ha.csv")

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet                          ' ditto for sht1
    Set sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sht1.Cells) <> 0 Then

        LastRow = sht1.Cells.Find( _
                        What:="*", _
                        After:=sht1.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If

    sht1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, sht1.Range("AA3"), xlYes).Name = "Table1"

    sht1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
                Field:=9, _
                Criteria1:=">=-1000000000000", _
                Operator:=xlAnd, _
                Criteria2:="<=1000000000000000"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False          ' not sure if needed

    Range("Table1[#All]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht2.Cells

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True           ' not sure if needed

    wb2.Save                                   ' already C:\Users\Ha.csv
    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I like how you cleaned it up.  For me though it creates a table from AA3 and then doesn't create a table to the 9th Column but just AA3-> End of that column.  I changed it to Field:=1 and I think there was an issue with copy and paste as well.  Sorry not sure why this is happening :S

Comment: does the code, that you posted, actually create a multi-column table? which line does that?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even bother with using VBA to get the data, use Power Query and import the data from the source file, perform the filter in the query and return the result to a table in the "FUA" workbook.

Then the query can be set to automatically refresh on the "FUA" workbook opening or in the query definition.